# Stuck on 'Case' assignment/wording

Tags: vba

Much thanks to the help I have received on the forum with this particular code; I thought I had it from there but I must beg you for your assistance one again. I think the best explanation I can give is below in the pseudo-code! Once this case selection portion is done I repeat the same process through the months so only would have to change the referenced cells.

```
Sub PopCol()


Range("D3:D19").Formula = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"  'D=C-B , Delta is equal to Cap minus Dem
    For i = 3 To 19
    Range("D" & i) = CLng(Range("C" & i) - Range("B" & i))
    If (Range("D" & i) < 0) Then
        Range("E" & i) = Range("E" & i) - Range("D" & i)
    Else
        Range("F" & i) = Range("F" & i) + Range("D" & i)
    End If
Next

Range("G3:G19").Formula = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"  'G=F-E , Delta is equal to Cap minus Dem

'if delta (h)= capacity (G) continue, if g<0 go back over prior months to where is negative and add   
 to    capacity
'then recalculate, else g>0 - go back over prior months and subtract(a neg) from demand (same as 
adding absolute value). then recalculate all.

For i = 3 To 19
    Range("G" & i) = CLng(Range("F" & i) - Range("E" & i))
Select Case (Range("G" & i)) 'May
   'Case "G" = Range ("F" & i)  Continue
Case Is = Range("F" & i)
          GoTo Line 35

'Case "G" < "0" check D if >0,("D"&i)=("D"&i)-("G" & i) 
     '{then compare D with C, balance over equal is placed in G and D & C end up equal. goto beginning of sub}
Case Is < "0"
        ("D"&i)=("D"&i)-("G" & i)else Goto Line 5

Case Else
     'case "G" > "0" check D if <0,("C"&i)=("C"&i)-("G" & i) "(then compare D with C, balance over 
equal is placed in G and D & C end up equal.goto beginning of sub}
    If Range("G" & i) > "0" Then
End Select

'next is June
For i = 3 To 19
    Range("J" & i) = CLng(Range("I" & i) - Range("H" & i))
Select Case "June"
    'Case "H" = Range ("F" & i)  Continue
    'Case "H" < "0" check G if >0,("G"&i)=("G"&i)-("J" & i) {then compare G with F, balance over 
equal    is placed in J and G & F end up equal. goto beginning of sub}
    'case "H" > "0" check G if <0,("F"&i)=("F"&i)-("J" & i) (then compare G with F, balance over equal 
is placed in J and G & F end up equal. goto beginning of sub}
End Select

Next

'COntinue on with July, August, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan 14, Feb 14 but in FEb 14 place balance over 
equal in

End Sub
```

Thank you SOOOO much!

Comment: What specifically is the question?

Comment: THe code listed explains it better than I could (even though I have no idea how to word it correctly!) Everything prior to the Case implementation works perfectly. This is to

Comment: This is what I don't know how to word! - "Case "G" = Range ("F" & i)  Continue
    Case Is = Range("F" & i)
              GoTo Line 35
        
Case "G" < "0" check D if >0,("D"&i)=("D"&i)-("G" & i) {then compare D with C, balance over equal is placed in G and D & C end up equal. goto beginning of sub}
Case Is < "0"
            ("D"&i)=("D"&i)-("G" & i)else Goto Line 5
       
    Case Else
case "G" > "0" check D if <0,("C"&i)=("C"&i)-("G" & i) "(then compare D with C, balance over equal is placed in G and D & C end up equal.goto beginning of sub}
        If Range("G" & i) > "0" Then

Comment: I still don't see what the **question** is...To put it simply, there is no sentence ending in a question mark. Try to compose one to clarify what you are looking for from answerers. **PLEASE** see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay then my question is simple I have no idea how to put what I have above in the correct format for a Select Case.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand. I have posted an example of what your code should resemble and hopefully you can fill in the blanks.

```
For i = 3 To 19
    Range("G" & i).Value = CLng(Range("F" & i).Value) - CLng(Range("E" & i).Value)
    Select Case CLng((Range("G" & i)).Value)
        Case CLng(Range("F" & i).Value)
              GoTo Line 35
        Case < "0"
            '("D"&i)=("D"&i)-("G" & i)else Goto Line 5  <--- very wrong, use the 2nd to see reformat this line.
        Case Else
            GoTo Line 35
    End Select
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that may be all I need! Still getting used to some of the wording/code so thank you for your patience!